# About the PHP geolocation

Tags: php

I'm using GeoPlugin for my php project now. But the plugin always give me the longitude and latitude which my service provider at, and what I want is the location of the user, anybody can help me?

```
<?php

  $user_ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
  $geo = unserialize(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?
  ip=$user_ip"));
  $log = $geo["geoplugin_latitude"];
  $lad = $geo["geoplugin_longitude"];
  echo "$log";
  echo "<br></br>";
  echo "$lad";
?>
```

Comment: You just then geocovert latitude and longitude to an area. Type it in Google, it's pretty simple. You just need to pick a service.

Comment: you can use getCurrentPosition() method.

Comment: Okay, thanks i go try now

Comment: @ProEvilz — How does converting the lat and long of the **service provider** to an area help find out where the **visitor** is?

Answer (score -2):

you can get city name by geoplugin_city,
Country Name by geoplugin_countryName
State name by geoplugin_region

Comment: What does that have to do with the question?

Comment: you want to access location of user right?

Comment: The problem the question is asking about is that `$user_ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');` is giving an IP address belonging to OP's service provider and not an IP address belonging to the visitor.

Comment: okay, the question is a bit confusing, basically, you want to track the ip